# How do I get the border to not surround everything else?

Tags: html, css

So I have this at the bottom right now and I don't know why but the border keeps surrounding all the images I have put above it. Can you guys help me? I just want it to surround just the text I have put in it. Sorry if this is such a simple question.

```
</body>
<body>
<h1 style="text-align:center;color:white;border-style: solid;"> <b> Text </b> </h1>
</body>
```

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle of this..

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=2qfIRKnsbk

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle and post all relevant code?

Comment: Yeah I just posted the jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of your problems stemimg from having multiple body tags. an page should never have more than one body tag. For what you're trying to do use `div` instead. if you want to apply styles to the body specify a div as a body wrapper and have everything else a child of this div so you dont apply styles directly to the body.

there are also multiple `head` tags you can put all the styles in the same place or in another file.